# Ho to use NgProgress with `HttpClient` and `HttpClientModule`?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'am using the **`NgProgress`** for a component and it's working fine and also when running an unit test.

I did implement an upgrade for **`HttpModule`** using the **`HttpClientModule`** which looks fine. My issue is that when I run the unit test I get following error:

**`[object ErrorEvent] thrown`**

**`Error: StaticInjectorError[NgProgress]: 
  StaticInjectorError[NgProgress]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgProgress!`**

The error is normally explaining itself, but I just can't get rid of it and fix it.

Is there any fix for that or a workaround? Did I miss any update or upgrade regarding **`NgProgress`**?

**`app.component.ts`**:

```
...
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgProgress } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';
...

constructor(..., public progress: NgProgress, ...) {...}

myFunction() {
    ...
    this.progress.complete();
    ....
}
```

**`app.component.spec.ts`**:

```
    import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
    import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { NgProgress } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';
    ....
    describe("myComponent", () => {

    let component: myComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;

    beforeEach(
        async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [
                    ...
                    RouterTestingModule,
                    HttpClientTestingModule,
                    ReactiveFormsModule,
                    ...
                ],
                declarations: [myComponent],
                providers: [
                    { provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefMock },
                    ...
                ],
                schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
            }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

});
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: True. More Code has been Added

Comment: Thank you, k.vincent, that's much more useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue fixed... solution is adding following code in Providers Array within `configureTestingModule({...})` Method:

```
...
providers: [
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefMock },
    ...
    { provide: NgProgress }
],
....
```